# Hourly cronjob does not work

Tags: cron

So just to sketch the outlines of this problem, i made an cronjob that should be executed on each full hour like this: 0:00, 1:00, 2:00. In all the manuals/tutorials i found on the internet they say putting in a crontab like this would do the trick:

```
0 * * * * echo "HourlyCronJobTest" > /home/sajvanderzeeuw/myCRON.txt
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Every other number of minutes does work. E.g. the job below which creates the text file at every 35 minutes of the hour. 0:35, 1:35 etc etc.

```
35 * * * * echo "HalfHourCronjobTest" > /home/sajvanderzeeuw/myCRON2.txt
```

So there is a easy way to circumvent this by simple doing it at 1 minute past the hour. But i just wonder if someone can show me why this happens.

Comment: What's the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: @Gx1sptDTDa Linux shark 3.13.0-55-generic #94-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 18 00:27:10 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: look strange, this should work, try `@hourly`  (in place of `"0 * * * *"`)

Comment: I know that this is also possible. Trying as we speak. But still this does not declare why it doesnt work for ```0 * * * *```

Comment: Very strange. Which version of cron do you have installed?

Comment: 4th Berkeley Distribution                                                                        19 April 2010                                                                                       CRONTAB(1)

Comment: Could you describe how you're testing this? Specifically, how are you altering the crontab file? And what do you before/after that to test whether it worked?

Comment: `0 * * * * echo "HourlyCronJobTest"  \`date\` >> /home/sajvanderzeeuw/myCRON.txt`
Can you test maybe doing this in-order to capture with the time & not overwriting the file.

Comment: Do any log entries appear for the `0 * * * *` line? They'd be in a file in `/var/log`, I forget which file it is on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Gilles i couldnt locate the log file in ```/var/log``` @Archemar ```@hourly``` seems to work.

Comment: @Kenster I am testing this with setting the 2 commands you see above. I put them in a crontab with this command: ```crontab -e``` BTW the command above was working on a older machine ubuntu 12.04 instead of 14.04. Since system was updated commands stop working.

Comment: The file is `/var/log/syslog`. When a cron job is executed, there's a line like `Jul 20 20:00:00 darkstar CRON[123]: (sajvanderzeeuw) CMD (echo "HourlyCronJobTest" > /home/sajvanderzeeuw/myCRON.txt)`

Comment: @Gilles unfortunately i am not allowed to see this file since it is on our calculation cluster and i am not the admin.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. It was not due to a bug in Cron but it was because the LDAP client of our compute cluster was restarted on the hour. So therefore all CRONjobs scheduled at this time weren't executed, because the cluster couldn't recognize user IDs.